# how Handling EF Core migrations in a team

Tags: asp.net, git, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, teamwork-projects

I got into an argument with a co-worker regarding EF Core migrations and how we should handle them in a team environment. The current process we use (which I designed) is to use a branch with our names and self databases so every changes we make , we add-migration in our databases and branches and then merge our branches to develop branch. to prevent conflicts with migrations we add migration folder in gitignore in our branches. but the problem is we dont have migration history in git. but i have problem with this becuase we should have all changes in git.

Are there any best practices regarding this? we want to have migration histories in git branches and prevent EF Core migrations in a team?

how Handle EF Core migrations conflict in a team with different branches?

Answer (score 1):

Everyone should be working on the same set of migrations checked into git. They can add (and remove) new ones locally while developing features, but as you said, they need to be careful when pushing and pulling changes that might conflict.

See [Migrations in Team Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/teams) for pointers.